# Oracle sql not reading the entire string

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I have a oracle sql query to get me the dates from 18/05/2021 to '28/05/2021'.

For some reason the the value after slash is not read, as the values from month 4 is also outputed. I dont know where i am wrong. Please give a hand if you are able, thanks a lot for your time.

NOTE: the dates have been stored in the database with a varchar datatype.

```
 SELECT datadate
 FROM mytable
 WHERE trailerid= '1'  and datattime>'05:00:00' and datattime<'12:00:00'
 AND datadate between '18/05/2021'  and '28/05/2021'
 GROUP BY datadate ORDER BY datadate;
```

Current output

```
DATADATE
----------------
18/05/2021
19/04/2021
19/05/2021
20/05/2021
21/04/2021
21/05/2021
22/04/2021
22/05/2021
23/04/2021
23/05/2021
24/04/2021
24/05/2021
25/04/2021
25/05/2021
26/04/2021
26/05/2021
27/04/2021
27/05/2021
28/04/2021
28/05/2021
```

Comment: Dates in this format are not ordered, because to compare dates you need to compare years first, then months, then days. The order of this parts in your string is different

Comment: *I dont know where i am wrong* - right around the part where you said: *the dates have been stored in the database with a varchar datatype* - no, no, no, no, no. Fix that fundamental problem and this consequential one goes away forever

Comment: Hey thanks, i reason i wanted to try with this is that i had huge chunks of data in that column. Now its seems like i have to start all over again. Thanks for answering

Comment: If you're going to stick with storing dates as strings, at the very least store them in yyyy-mm-dd so that BETWEEN works.. You complain that `BETWEEN '18/05..' AND '28/05..'` returns 04 dates, but string `19/04..` really is between for same reason that "M/A" is between "L/Y" and "Z/Z" even though A is not between Y and Z! Honestly, it'll take about 5 minutes to add another column of a datetime type, copy the data to it, delete the old column and rename the new back to the old. Also, bonus, your new shiny DATETIME column can store the contents of datatime too.

Comment: Storing dates as string will also mess up optimizer statistics, potentially leading to bad execution plans

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when people store date values as strings.

See if this helps:

```
 AND to_date(datadate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') between to_date('18/05/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')  
                                         and to_date('28/05/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, but it shows an error :( Its not a valid match

Comment: Exactly as I said - that's what happens when people store values as strings. Some values in that column don't follow that date format and Oracle raises an error. There's nothing much you can do about it, but to find and fix invalid values. A simple but inefficient option to do that is to use a loop and store (or display) invalid rows so that you could fix them afterwards.

Comment: Did you mean to wrap `datadate` within `to_date` too? I thought that was the whole point of your answer.

Comment: Absolutely, @mathguy. Thank you. I should try not to do several things at a time, the result is really poor :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to start over, just move the data to a datetime column

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD x DATE;

UPDATE t SET x = to_date(concat(datadate,datatime), 'dd/mm/yyyyhh24:mi:ss'))
WHERE datadate in (SELECT to_char(to_date('1999-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + level, 'dd/mm/yyyy') FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 10000)
```

That WH ERE clause should generate a list of valid dates from 2000 to about 2030 - if you have dates outside this range adjust accordingly

Should now be able to find invalid dates (they weren't part of the where clause and x should hence remain null) and fix manually:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x is null
```

Then drop your datadate and datatime cols and rename x to datadatetime

Now queries like BETWEEN work properly, and if you need just the date part you can do TRUNC(x). (You can even TRUNC to other date parts like hours, to cut the minutes and seconds off, or week of year to round dates down to the start of the week etc)
If you need just the time you either do `x - TRUNC(x)` which gives a decimal number like 0.5 for 12 noon or 0.75 for 6pm, or you can TOCHAR depending on what you want to do. It would be better to do `x -TRUNC(x) BETWEEN 9.0/24.0 AND 17.0/24.0` than doing a string compare

Comment: While your overall approach is sound, there is no DATETIME data type in oracle.  The correct data type for this application is DATE  (ALTER TABLE t ADD x DATE;)

Comment: Update made, Thanks Ed